# How can i log in using a name and a password stored in two different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, admin

```
public class Coach extends Team {

    private int Code;

    public Coach(String name, String team, int age) {
        super(name, team, age);
    }

    public Coach() {

    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.Code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return Code;
    }

    public String code[] = {
        "qwe",
        "asd",
        "zxc"
    };

    public String CoachName[] = {
        "person1",
        "person2",
        "person3"
    };
}
```

The main class

```
import com.org.FS.Coach;
import com.org.FS.Team;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Federation System!! \n\nPlease enter your name:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nHi " + name + " !!\n\nPlease select an option\n 1- Guest and 2- Admin : \n Guest    Admin ");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You choose  --- " + choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Table Info");
            System.out.println("=============================================================");
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("  ==Log in== ");

        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            Card c = new Card();
            System.out.println("                    ==Players==\n" + c);
            System.out.println("==============================================================");

        } else if (choice == 2) {  
            Coach co=new Coach();

            System.out.println("Enter username:\n");
            name=input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\n\nWelcome " + name + "\nPlease enter your verification code :");  
            String code1=input.nextLine();

            for(int i=0;i<co.CoachName.length;i++)   {

                if( name.equals(co.CoachName[i]) || code1.equals(co.code[i]) && (!co.getName().equals(co.CoachName[++i]) || !co.code.equals(co.code[++i])) )
                    System.out.println("Wrong code!\nTry Again!");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Success !");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my project contains 5 classes named
TeamTest1(the main class)
Team 
Players 
Coach 
and Card
 the team class is the superclass and have coach and players as subclasses.
When i run the code and i press 1 the guest it shows only the players information.If i press two Admin,i want to put the name person1 like i have it in the array and the password too.Im very confused if i need to creATE A new array or to use the one i have...

Comment: Can you please format your code.

Comment: ... and add more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Sure,im sorry its my first project inn java and i have stuck.

Comment: You will need to loop to start again the workflow.. and what the problem comparing the credentials?

Comment: I'd like to answer the question but there're so many things to say. I don't even know where to start... Why did you store in two different arrays the login and the password ? You obviously need to have a link between the two pieces of information...

Comment: I thought to call it with a for loop or something :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting user input repeatedly you can use a while loop like so

```
int choice = input.nextInt();
while (choice != 3) {
    ...
    choice = input.nextInt();
}
```

for getting (user,password) pairs you can use a map like so

```
Map users = new HashMap(); 
m.put("person1", "qwe");
m.put("person2", "asd");
m.put("person3", "zxc");
```

and check if the key value match

```
value = m.get(co.CoachName)
if code.equals(value) ....
```

Don't forget to use try catch and/or check for integrity of user input and keys exists in map and so...